# What does this malware code in application do?

Tags: php, malware

Hi i have found certain code injected into my php application.
Does any know how this is possible and also explain me how to avoid such injections.
The code is present under the src attribute of img tag.
Kindly help figure it out what does this code do?

```
src='data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD/7QhcUGhvdG9zaG9wIDMuMAA4QklNA+0AAAAAABAASAAAAAEA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='
```

Comment: This is not really a good question for the [so] format.  Questions here should be more specific and need to show some effort on the side of the asker - research/what have you tried...etc...

Comment: What your question should be in my opinion is how to correctly secure your application.  There are many resources on the internet to teach you how to secure your site.  Why don't you try to implement some such methods and if you come across a problem with one of them - come back here, post about it and explain what you have tried so far and what issues you have come across.

Comment: Im it's current form - I am afraid that your question will have some difficulty getting an answer.

Answer (score 2):

This "malicious code" is JPEG image.

Like this : [image]

Answer (score 0):

there is nothing wrong with this code. it is only a base64 encoded byte array of an image.

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out, this is just an image that is byte-encoded. You can avoid such injections by properly escaping user input before displaying it/storing it (e.g. in your database). You should take a look at [HTMLPurifier](http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCgQFjAA&url=http://htmlpurifier.org/&ei=vSxnT8bcEM-OswbxvNDEBQ&usg=AFQjCNGUdBlB8Vv5p3oSWpi9EV-P0K8UBQ).

Answer (score 0):

This is not a malware code. This actually is an image. (I can even tell you that is has been created/modified in Photoshop3.0) There is something wrong with your code somewhere else. It looks like you are using the data itself as the name of the file.